# Null value in the first itemUnselect event on primefaces autoComplete

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I am facing a strange situation when using primefaces p:autoComplete. I put this piece of code in a xhtml file, inside a h:form tag:

```
                    <p:autoComplete id="to" 
                                    multiple="true" 
                                    value="#{editEmailComponent.receiversEntitiesToDummy}" 
                                    completeMethod="#{editEmailComponent.completeQuery}"
                                    emptyMessage="#{text['list.empty']}"                                            
                                    var="ent"
                                    itemLabel="#{ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityGroupHeader'? ent.design : (ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityContactList'? ent.email : ent.abstractEntityEmail)}"
                                    itemValue="#{ent}"
                                    forceSelection="true"
                                    cache="false"
                                    styleClass="full-width"
                                    autocomplete="none">
                        <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" 
                                     list="#{editEmailComponent.receiversAllConverter}" />
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{(ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityGroupHeader') and (ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityContactList')}" value="\# #{ent.number}" />
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityGroupHeader'}" value="\# #{ent.design}" />
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityContactList'}" value="#{ent.nif}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{(ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityGroupHeader') and (ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityContactList')}" value="#{ent.abstractEntityDesignation}" />
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityContactList'}" value="#{ent.designation}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{(ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityGroupHeader') and (ent.class.simpleName ne 'EntityContactList')}" value="#{ent.abstractEntityEmail}" />
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{ent.class.simpleName eq 'EntityContactList'}" value="#{ent.email}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:ajax event="query" process="@this"/>
                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@form" listener="#{editEmailComponent.onItemSelectTo}" update="to" />
                        <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" process="@form" listener="#{editEmailComponent.onItemUnselectTo}" update="to" />
                    </p:autoComplete>
```

The action associated to this  itemUnselect event is:

```
  public void onItemUnselectTo(UnselectEvent event) {

    onItemUnselect(receiversEntitiesToDummy, event);
    BaseObject obj2 = (BaseObject) event.getObject();

    //Instancia da entidade e converter para receiver
    if(obj2 instanceof EntityContactList){
        EntityContactList aux = (EntityContactList) obj2;
        for(Receiver rec : receiversTo)
            if(rec.getEntity().equals(aux.getEntity()))
                receiversTo.remove(rec);
    }

    private static void onItemUnselect(List<BaseObject> list, UnselectEvent event) {        
        BaseObject obj = (BaseObject) event.getObject();   
        list.remove(obj);        
    }
```

I initialize the list of this autocomplete like this:

```
private List<BaseObject> receiversEntitiesToDummy = new ArrayList<>();
...
EntityContactList result = entityManager.getEntityContactList(receiver.getEntity(),null);
receiversEntitiesToDummy.add(result);
```

So, when I remove this first element the "obj2" is null but when I search and select some object the "obj2" is properly filled. Anyone knows why this happens?

Note: I am using primefaces 5.2.

Comment: Try PF 6 or 7 or 8 first... with your [mcve]. And/or check their releasenotes, maybe you can already see a fix so you know it is solved in a newer version.

Comment: Can you try removing the update, from ajax?

Comment: @WoAiNii is right, updating yourself on an ajax call is bad practice.

Comment: Ok...but nothing changes with this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem changing the way I populate the list with the first element.

Instead of this:

```
private List<BaseObject> receiversEntitiesToDummy = new ArrayList<>();
...
EntityContactList result = entityManager.getEntityContactList(receiver.getEntity(),null);
receiversEntitiesToDummy.add(result);
```

I put the first element using the query function and it works.

```
EntityContactList result = entityManager.getEntityContactList(receiver.getEntity(),null);

List<BaseObject> aux = new ArrayList<>();
if(receiver.getEntity().getAbstractEntityEmail() != null)
    aux = completeQuery(receiver.getEntity().getAbstractEntityEmail());

if(aux.contains(result)){
   int num = aux.indexOf(result);
   EntityContactList another =  (EntityContactList) aux.get(num);
   receiversEntitiesToDummy.add(another);
}
```